# MySQL Many-to-many relationship problem

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables in mysql `artists` `tracks` and `artist_tracks`
and i did what was written in [this](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html) aricle.

this is the tables `artist`:artist_id, artist_name
`tracks`:track_id, track_name
`artist_tracks`: `artist_id`, `track_id`

how can i prevent duplicate rows in `artist_tracks` table ??

Comment: If you have constructed your primary keys properly you shouldn't be able to create duplicate rows.

Comment: declare artist_id **and** track_id as primary key in artist_tracks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a composite primary key around both the `artist_id` and `track_id` columns.  This is standard practice for bridge tables.

```
ALTER TABLE artist_tracks DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE artist_tracks ADD PRIMARY KEY (artist_id, track_id);
```

If you followed that article correctly, you should already have such a key and so duplicates will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX artist_id_track_id ON artist_tracks (artist_id, track_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did what was in the link you are already preventing duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
  `a_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL default '',
  `b_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`a_id`,`b_id`)
)
```

This code does that for you by making a composite primary key from the ids of artist and track.

Answer (score 0):

You need group_concat and a "convoluted" join on the 3 tables, 
see this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c6f/3/0